# Expected payout from two banks with limited money based on fair coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose there are 2 banks with equal money units. A fair coin toss decides which bank loses 1 unit of money to the tosser i.e. if result is heads, Bank A loses 1 unit and if the result is tails, Bank B loses 1 unit. Bank A always wins with heads and bank B always wins with tails. The tosser is a third party in the game. The game stops when a bank runs out of money and then loses the toss.

What is the expected payout of the tosser?

Comment: To be clear, bank B loses 1 unit of money to the tosser if the result is tails? And we assume that the banks start with say $n$ units of money?

Comment: Both banks lose 1 unit of money to the tosser every time they lose the toss. Yes, both banks start with _n_ units.

Comment: Okay, because your comment "Bank B loses 1 unit, always" suggests that Bank B loses 1 unit of money regardless of the result of the coin flip.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to make what I meant, clearer.

Comment: Does the order of the flips matter? For example, if $n=2$, would we distinguish the outcome in which bank A loses, bank B loses, and then bank A loses from the outcome in which bank B loses and then bank A loses twice in a row? Or are we only interested in the resulting payout of the tosser?

Comment: The order of the flips do not matter. We are only interested in the payout of the tosser. But, just to clarify, with respect to the outcomes you mentioned above, the game wouldn't end at the 3rd toss, it can go on till a bank which has no money loses the toss.

Comment: Oh I see, the game ends when the bank reaches $-1$ net worth.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I will have to take some time to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Banach's matchbox puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem) and a full solution (for number of money units left in the non-losing bank) is given.  From that you can calculate its expectation and then the tosser's expected profit.

If you're looking for a hint (before checking wikipedia), the solution involves the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Huh, I would never have guessed this answer. Interesting question indeed...